# How to create permanent subl link for Sublime Text 3? (Mac Catalina)

Tags: macos, terminal, sublimetext3, symlink

I'm new to working with Terminal and I'm trying to create a symlink to Sublime Text 3 in Terminal. I've already tried this `ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/.` but unfortunately it says "ln: /usr/local/bin/./subl: Permission denied". Also tried this: https://olivierlacan.com/posts/launch-sublime-text-3-from-the-command-line/ . But it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`sudo`](https://ss64.com/osx/sudo.html):

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

You'll have to type in your password (assuming you have an administrator account), but it should work then.

Even using `sudo`, the exact command you put in your question wouldn't work, as it's attempting to symlink `/usr/local/bin/.` to the `subl` executable. Using `/usr/local/bin/subl` will work.